# adding cells to existing rows using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a pre-defined table with all rows hidden like this:

```
<tr id="row1" style="display: none;">
</tr>
<tr id="row2" style="display: none;">
</tr>
<tr id="row3" style="display: none;">
</tr>
<tr id="row4" style="display: none;">
</tr>
<tr id="row5" style="display: none;">
</tr>
<tr id="row6" style="display: none;">
</tr>
```

I am trying to use Javascript to add cells to each row and then show it. My javascript currently gets the row id and at the end it will show that row. but I can't figure out how to add cells to it, here my function:

```
function CreateTable(numberOfLines, linesCollection, displayCollection) {
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
                var rowId = 'row' + (i + 1);
                var row = document.getElementById(rowId);


                document.getElementById('row' + (i + 1)).style.display = "";

          }
        }
```

Comment: You want [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
var TD = document.createElement('td'); //Create new cell
TD.innerHTML = 'This is a new cell added'; //Set some thing
row.appendChild (TD); //Add it to row
```

Comment: is there a way to delete that child in a different JavaScript?